# Scope variable in maxscript

Tags: variables, scope, maxscript

How do I pass the variable from one scope to another? I cannot predeclare it as the object is defined only when the user picks the object. Actually this code fails because it tries to read a local variable defined in another scope.

In pseudo code:

1.pick an object
2.copy the selected object

And the actual code:

```
macroScript Variables
category:"Stackoverflow"
toolTip:""

(

rollout Roll "Scopes"
(
 pickbutton pickobj "Pick object"
on pickobj picked objectPicked do if isValidNode objectPicked do pickobj.tooltip = "You picked " + objectPicked.name 

button pass "Pass the variable"
on pass pressed do (

newObj = copy objectPicked
print newObj

)
)
createDialog Roll 300 80

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's really simple as you can access the pickButton's object property:

```
rollout Roll "Scopes"
(
    pickButton pickObj "Pick object" autoDisplay:true
    button pass "Pass the variable"

    on pickObj picked objectPicked do
        if isValidNode objectPicked do
            pickobj.tooltip = "You picked " + objectPicked.name 

    on pass pressed do
    (
        local newObj = copy pickobj.object
        print newObj
    )
)
createDialog Roll 300 80
```

But even without that, you can assign the node to a variable that's in a accessible scope:

```
rollout Roll "Scopes"
(
    local pickedObj

    pickbutton pickobj "Pick object" autoDisplay:true
    button pass "Pass the variable"

    on pickobj picked objectPicked do
        if isValidNode objectPicked do
        (
            pickedObj = objectPicked
            pickobj.tooltip = "You picked " + objectPicked.name
        )

    on pass pressed do
    (
        local newObj = copy pickedObj
        print newObj
    )
)
createDialog Roll 300 80
```